TypeScript, ESLint and unused value
Here's my type for a project that uses Google Maps. onMarkerAdd is a callback function, which returns nothing and changes the state, as you can see below.
export type MapProps = {
  markers: Coordinates[];
 onMarkerAdd: (coordinates: Coordinates) => void;
} & ModeProps;

coordinates look like this: { lat: 0.5, lng: 0.1 }
 const onMarkerAdd = useCallback((coordinates: Coordinates) => {
    setMarkers((prevMarkers) => [...prevMarkers, coordinates]);
  }, []);

I created the onMarkerAdd function inside a parent component and pass it as a prop to a child one.
The code for the child component is located below. Note only use the onMarkerAdd function if necessary:
export const OrderMap: React.FC<MapProps> = ({ markers, onMarkerAdd, mode, toggleMode }) => {

...

 const OnMapClick = useCallback(
    (location: LocationObject) => {
      if (mode === MAP_MODES.SET_MARKER) {
        const lat = location.latLng.lat();
        const lng = location.latLng.lng();
        onMarkerAdd({ lat, lng });
      }
    },
    [mode, onMarkerAdd]
  );

The problem is that I get an error from ESLint that says: "ESLint: 'coordinates' is defined but never used.(no-unused-vars)". It appears inside the MapProps type, above the "coordinates" prop in the onMarkerAdd function.
